# react native stuck after bundle: Done copying assets

Tags: react-native

My `react-native run-ios --device` stuck after displaying this line.
simulator does not stuck.

I tried

```
`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build/ModuleCache/* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm i`.
```

No luck.

```
bundle: Done writing bundle output

bundle: Copying 84 asset files

bundle: Done copying assets

+ [[ ! -n false ]]
```

Same on using xcode build.
Xcode says `running 2 of 4 custom shell scripts` and report navigator displays

```
bundle: Done writing bundle output

bundle: Copying 84 asset files

bundle: Done copying assets

+ [[ ! -n false ]]
```

Any suggestion?

react-native: 0.44.0

Comment: Have you succeeded?